# How do I limit a select by a sum?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, limit

I want to select all the cheapest toys of my stock, amounting a total of 10.0 USD:

That is, I want to do something that looks like this:

`select * from toy where sum(price) < 10.0 order by price;`

What would be the correct SQL?

To make it clearer, I'll add an example.
Suppose I have these items in my table:

```
       name       | price
------------------+-------
car               |     1
boat              |     2
telephone         |     8
gold bar          |    50
```

The result I would be: 1 car and 1 boat.

Totaling the price of 3 USD. I cannot select the telephone because it would amount 13 USD, and that is larger than 10.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What RDBMS are you running?

Comment: how are the records sorted? do you have an auto increment key?

Comment: They are randomly sorted. I would like to sort by the price.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
SELECT a.name, max(a.price) price 
FROM Toy a
JOIN Toy b
  on a.price > b.price or (a.price=b.price and a.name>=b.name)
GROUP BY a.name
HAVING SUM(b.price) <= 10.0
order by 2
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3faec/3).

Comment: +1 Query works as per OP's requirement. Can you please explain the given query?

Comment: @hims056: Sure - for each record on `Toy` (alias a) the query links to all records on the same table (alias b) that have a lower price (or the same price but a lower or equal name), then checks whether the linked records' prices add up to no more than 10.

Comment: I would assume that using a window function to calculate the running sum (see Clodoaldo's answer) will be more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3faec/10)

```
select name, price, total
from (
    select
        name, price,
        sum(price) over(
            order by price
            rows between unbounded preceding and current row
        ) total
    from toy
) s
where total <= 10
order by price
```

Notice that while `between unbounded preceding and current row` is the default frame, the default mode is `range`. So it is necessary to have at least `rows unbounded preceding` declared as the current row is the frame end default.

Comment: Just a side note: specifying `rows between unbounded preceding and current row` is not really necessary as that is the default.

Answer (score 2):

Here is implementation using recursive CTE. There are other solutions for this, you can google for "running totals".

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE_RN  AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Price) RN FROM Toys
)
, CTE_Rec AS
(
    SELECT name, price, rn FROM CTE_RN WHERE RN = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECt r.name, a.price + r.price as price, r.rn FROM CTE_RN r
    INNER JOIN CTE_Rec a on a.RN + 1 = r.RN
    where a.price+r.price <= 10
 )
SELECT name, price as total_price FROM CTE_Rec
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/bb1c5/5)

PS:  It greatly depends on RDBMS, so that's why it was important to include that info at the start.